# How to save the return from Mongoose exec function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save the return from the following function:

```
let maxNum;

const result = Url.find({})
 .sort({short_url: - 1})
 .select('short_url')
 .exec((err, data) => {
 console.log('what is data', data)
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   console.log('what is data here', data[0].short_url)
   maxNum = data[0].short_url;
 });

    console.log("resultsssss", result);
    console.log('give me maxnum', maxNum);
```

What I am getting back is:

```
resultsssss undefined
give me maxnum undefined
what is data [ { _id: 5ed434038de5842a1b14c44d, short_url: 2 },
  { _id: 5ed432937439e628e98e43e4, short_url: 1 },
  { _id: 5ed57d1dbd11721236587e2b } ]
what is data here 2
```

You can see if I log inside the exec then I get the data but I can't get the whole thing outside of that and keeps giving me undefined. How can I get the data so I can save it to a variable outside of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` call is asynchronous so by the time you console.log, the function has not completed running yet.

Simply move your console.log into the callback of the `exec` call.

```
let maxNum;

const result = Url.find({})
 .sort({short_url: - 1})
 .select('short_url')
 .exec((err, data) => {
   if (err) return console.log(err);

   console.log('what is data', data)

   console.log('what is data here', data[0].short_url)
   maxNum = data[0].short_url;
   console.log('give me maxnum', maxNum); 
 });
```

or use `await` statement:

```
    const result = await Url.find({})
     .sort({short_url: - 1})
     .select('short_url')
     .exec();

    // access whatever you need
    const maxNum = result[0].short_url;
```

Comment: Yeah but I need it to be outside as I will need to use the value to do something with it hence why I saved it to result variable

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Just deleted err and data as it's not defined.

Comment: no prob, please remember to mark the answer as correct if it helped solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

your promise doesn't return the result you have to add somthing like `.then(if(user){return user})`